# XPATH filter elements by tag name in XML query

Tags: xml, xpath

I am using MTConnect to read data from one of my machines am faced with getting multiple items from one query. I'm trying to query the web server like so: 
http://192.168.1.5:5006//sample?path=//Path[@name="block"]&count=1000
I want multiple blocks to be returned (around 500) but am ending up with everything else as well.

```
  <ComponentStream component="Path" name="path" componentId="path1_01">
```

The search throws an exception of

```
  <Error errorCode="INVALID_XPATH"> The path could not be parsed.
```

when I remove [@name="block"] from the equation this is what is returned:

```
 <ComponentStream component="Path" name="path" componentId="path1_01">

 <Samples>
 <PathPosition dataItemId="path17_01" timestamp="2018-01-16T22:00:26.555Z" 
 name="path_position" sequence="488485" subType="ACTUAL">
 -35559.9300000000 25399.9400000000 -3349.5800000000
 </PathPosition>
 <PathFeedrate dataItemId="path18_01" timestamp="2018-01-16T22:00:26.711Z" 
 name="path_feedrate" sequence="488490" subType="ACTUAL">4592</PathFeedrate>
 <Program dataItemId="path14_01" timestamp="2018-01-16T22:00:45.656396Z" 
 name="program" sequence="488654">UNAVAILABLE</Program>
 <Events>
 <Block dataItemId="path15_01" timestamp="2018-01-16T20:49:37.922Z" 
 name="block" sequence="393138"/>
 <Block dataItemId="path15_01" timestamp="2018-01-16T22:00:13.133Z" 
 name="block" sequence="488159">O0000%</Block>
 </Events>
```

How do I get multiple results from a single tag name ("block") from this query?

Comment: Did you try 

   http://192.168.1.5:5006//sample?path=//*[@name="block"]&count=1000
?

Comment: I just tried that and this is what I get in return:

Comment: <Error errorCode="INVALID_XPATH">
The path could not be parsed. Invalid syntax: /*[@name="block"]
</Error>

Comment: I take that back just needed to add an extra / in /*,  Thank you for your help!

Comment: you are right, i forgot that :)